# Why accept Metropolis-Hastings sample if more probable than previous sample?

Tags: sampling, metropolis-hastings

One step in the [Metropolis-Hastings sampling algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metropolis%E2%80%93Hastings_algorithm) is to determine whether a sample $x_i$ is to be accepted based on the previous sample $x_{i-1}$. My understanding is that $x_i$ is accepted with probability $P(x_i)/P(x_{i-1})$ (treated as certain if greater than 1). I essentially understand the reasoning behind this scheme, but why would we want to compare the probability of a sample to the previous sample? In other words, what is wrong with the following naive sampling algorithm?

1. Choose an arbitrary $x_0$.
2. Accept $x_0$ with probability $P(x_0)$.
3. Repeat for $x_i$.

What is the need for a specialized sampling distribution?

Comment: I have changed  $P(x{i-1})$ to $P(x_{i-1})$, as I believe was intended. (Close inspection of the latex reveals {} around the "i-1" but it was missing the "_" in front.) In the event my interpretation is incorrect then please revert my edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You typically cannot compute the probability $P$, it is only known up to a multiplicative constant. To see why, consider Bayes theorem:

$$P(\theta|x) = \frac{P(x|\theta)P(\theta)}{\displaystyle{\int_{\theta'} P(x|\theta')P(\theta')~\mathrm{d}\theta'}}$$

The numerator can be easy enough to compute, but the denominator is generally an intractable integral in many dimensions.

In addition, even if you knew the denominator (also known as the partition function, or the evidence), your technique (rejection sampling) might take a very long time to produce a sample, whereas in many cases, a Metropolis-Hastings chain can take advantage of the shape of the distribution to move towards the mass of that distribution.